# How to prevent duplicate records in Blazor server-side with Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor server-side with Sql Server. I want to prevent duplicate records in my table. I don't to use unique index in Sql Server. I want to check it before insert into the database?

Services.cs

```
using Test.Data;
using Test.Models.Moodle;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Test.Services.Moodle
{
    public class MoodleService:IMoodleService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public MoodleService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<List<MoodleTableModel>> Get()
        {
            return await _context.MoodleTablesList.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<MoodleTableModel> Get(int id)
        {
            var moodle = await _context.MoodleTablesList.FindAsync(id);
            return moodle;
        }

        public async Task<MoodleTableModel> Add(MoodleTableModel moodle)
        {
            _context.MoodleTablesList.Add(moodle);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return moodle;
        }
        public async Task<MoodleTableModel> Update(MoodleTableModel moodle)
        {
            _context.Entry(moodle).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return moodle;
        }
        public async Task<MoodleTableModel> Delete(int id)
        {
            var moodle = await _context.MoodleTablesList.FindAsync(id);
            _context.MoodleTablesList.Remove(moodle);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return moodle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's revise your question, delete it or close it.

Comment: Your test will always return true since `model.day == model.day` and `model.time == model.time` will always be true. Edit the question with more detail and a minimal working code sample

Comment: " I want to check it before insert into the database?" Agree with Omid Ataei, it is better to use the **[.Any method](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/23654057/check-if-record-exists-in-entity-framework)** to check whether the record Exists. Code as below: "if (context.MyEntity.Any(o => o.Id == idToMatch)) {  // Match!} else { //Not Match }", if you don't like this method, you could also use **Where clause** to find the record based on the  new record, if you could find the existing item, then, do something.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but actually I changed my services method to check it. It's work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public async Task<bool> Add(MoodleTableModel moodle)
    {//Condition to prevent duplicate
        MoodleTableModel existingmoodle = await _dbContext.MoodleTableModel .FirstOrDefaultAsync(
m => m.Room== moodle.Room && m.Day== moodle.Day);
        if (existingmoodle != null)
        {
            
           await Delete(moodle.Id);
        }
        else
        {moodle.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _dbContext.Add(moodle);
        }

        try
        {
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dbcontext.MoodleTableList.Any() to check if there is any record in db before insert

Comment: Thank you for your replay but actually I need condition to check many column like 
   ` if(moodle.Room ==moodle.Room && moodle.Day == moodle.Day){   Something like error message}else {   _context.MoodleTablesList.Add(moodle);}`